# Dashundergaps package: How do I change the underline thickness? How do I raise or lower the underline?

Tags: packages, gap

Dashundergaps package: How do I change the underline thickness? How do I raise or lower the underline?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{dashundergaps}
\dashundergapssetup{
    ,gap-number-format = \,
    \textsuperscript{\normalfont (\thegapnumber)},
    teacher-gap-format = underline,
    gap-widen,gap-extend-percent=100}
\TeacherModeOn
\begin{document}
\gap*{test}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dashundergaps` package uses underlining commands from the `ulem` package internally. Therefore you can modify the definitions from `ulem` as described in the [manual for that package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ulem/ulem.pdf) on page 3. For example by using a `\rule` with thickness 1.4pt and raised -4pt (i.e., lowered 4pt), or raised 1pt:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{dashundergaps}
\dashundergapssetup{
    ,gap-number-format = \,
    \textsuperscript{\normalfont (\thegapnumber)},
    teacher-gap-format = underline,
    gap-widen,gap-extend-percent=100}
\TeacherModeOn
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\uline{\bgroup\markoverwith
{\raisebox{-4pt}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{1.4pt}}}\ULon}

\gap*{test}

\renewcommand\uline{\bgroup\markoverwith
{\raisebox{1pt}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{1.4pt}}}\ULon}
\gap*{test}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]